# How to hide MvcSiteMapNode from menu but not breadcrumbs?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvcsitemapprovider

I have a certain page which I *don't* want showing up in the menu.  However, when I am on the page, I *do* want it to show up in the breadcrumbs.

I'm trying to do this with an `ISiteMapNodeVisibilityProvider` class, but can't figure out how to determine whether the provided `SiteMapNode` argument is inside the menu or breadcrumbs.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test which HTML helper is calling the visibility provider by checking the "HtmlHelper" element of the sourceMetadata parameter. This parameter is passed into the visibility provider automatically.

The names used are the type's FullName (the fully qualified name without the assembly name).

```
public class MyNodeNotOnMenuVisibilityProvider
    : SiteMapNodeVisibilityProviderBase
{
    public override bool IsVisible(ISiteMapNode node, IDictionary<string, object> sourceMetadata)
    {
        if (sourceMetadata.ContainsKey("HtmlHelper") && sourceMetadata["HtmlHelper"].ToString().Equals("MvcSiteMapProvider.Web.Html.MenuHelper"))
        {
            if (node.Key == "MyNode")
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

In v4, you can also pass custom information through any HTML helper using sourceMetadata, and then you can also test for custom information in your custom visibility provider.

```
@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu(new { myInfo = "Something" })
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple method of filtering menu items is by role. If you are not bound to a ISiteMapVisibilityProvider solution, you can modify the sitemap file and/or use the Authorize attribute. Hopefully one of these can help.

```
Mvc.sitemap:
<mvcSiteMapNode title="Secret Page" controller="RestrictedController" action="SecretAction" key="SecretPage" roles="MySecretRole" />

Controller/Action:
[Authorize(Roles="MySecretRole")]
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question.  Assume the user is authorized to see the page already.  I want to know how to *hide* a node from the menu, and *show* it in the breadcrumbs.  Some pages I just don't want to show up in the menu.  But when I'm on the page, I want it to show up in the breadcrumbs.

Answer (score -1):

```
To hide the menu item but keep the breadcrumbs, follow this: Here i am removing the child node "Products", but it will show in breadcrumbs.

<ul id="menu-nav" class="sf-menu" style="position:relative;transform:translateX(-50%);left:50%;margin-top:0px;">
@foreach (var node in Model.Nodes) { 
   <li class="current">@Html.DisplayFor(m => node)
        @if (node.Children.Any()) {  
            if(node.Children.Count > 0)
           {
                for(int n=0;n < node.Children.Count;n++)
                {
                    if(node.Children[n].Title == "Products")
                    {
                        node.Children.RemoveAt(n); 
                    }                                                                                
                }
                @Html.DisplayFor(m => node.Children)
           }          
        }
    </li>
}
```

Comment: This is a really shitty solution. You're just hardcoding all the names of the pages in your template...